# Pdf downloader in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need a solution to download app screen as pdf in React native. The below code is not working for me, and it is not a exact solution.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
} = from 'react-native';

import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

class Example extends Component {
    async createPDF() {
        let options = {
            html: '<h1>PDF TEST</h1>',
            fileName: 'test',
            directory: 'docs',
        };

        let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
        console.log(file.filePath);
      },

    render() {
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.createPDF}>
                <Text>Create PDF</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just copy-pasted some code snippet from the readme file of react-native-html-to-pdf, it is appreciated if you actually do some effort ...

To answer your question: this library will not help you in any way since a react-native screen does not consist out of html/css.

If you want a pdf from a react-native screen you probably first want to take a screenshot, and afterwards convert that jpeg image to pdf.